# calculate the arithmetic mean

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I would like to know how to calculate the arithmetic mean for all of two consecutive elements in a python-numpy array, and save the values in another array

```
col1sortedunique = [0.0610754, 0.27365186, 0.37697331, 0.46547072, 0.69995587, 0.72998093, 0.85794189]
```

thank you

Comment: What is in your source array which would be used to generate the example result?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly you want to do something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(0,10)
>>> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

```py
conse_mean = (arr[:-1]+arr[1:])/2
>>> array([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5])
```

so that would be a mapping from an array with length `N` to one with length `N-1`.

Maybe an additional explanation of the syntax:

```py
arr[1:])
>>> array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

would give you your array from without the first element and

```py
arr[:-1])
>>> array([0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

without the last.
Therefore you have two smaller arrays where a element and its consecutive neighbor have the same index and you can just calculate the mean as it is done above.